GitLab CI_CONFIG_PATH doesn't work with Pipeline trigger token for another
GitLab CI_CONFIG_PATH doesn't work with Pipeline trigger token for another project. The used call is
curl -X POST --fail -F $F_0  -F $F_1 -F $F_2 -F $F_3 -F $F_4 $URL_another_project

where $F_3 represents
"variables[CI_CONFIG_PATH]=cicd_helpers/diag_client/.gitlab-ci.yml"

Expected behavior:

another_project pipeline defined in the CI_CONFIG_PATH starts

Actual behavior:

default .gitlab-ci.yml pipeline in another_project starts.

The context value of CI_CONFIG_PATH in the executed (default) pipeline in another_project is set as expected, heaving the value "cicd_helpers/diag_client/.gitlab-ci.yml". Despite this incoming env, the default started.
My understanding is the CI_CONFIG_PATH value, in this case cicd_helpers/diag_client/.gitlab-ci.yml, defines the pipeline code. Obviously in my case this is ignored and the default .gitlab-ci.yml code is executed.
Any hint appreciated. Thnx.
